# Is it possible to get a PWD column in top output?

Tags: monitoring, ps, top

I know about `pwdx`, but it would be really nice if `top` showed the PWD: in other words, I want to see PWD and CPU/mem usage side by side. Does anyone have a script or one-liner to combine the output from `top`/`ps` with `pwdx` with periodic refresh?

Comment: You can combine `top`, `pwdx`, and `awk` to generate such a report.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my abominable solution:

`ps --no-headers -e -o pid,%cpu,%mem,args | grep -v "ps --no-headers" > ps.txt && awk '{ print $1 }' ps.txt > pids.txt && cat pids.txt | xargs pwdx | cut -d ' ' -f 2 > pwd.txt && awk '{ print " "$1" "$2" "$3" "}'  ps.txt > ps1.txt && cut -d ' ' -f 4- ps.txt  > ps2.txt && paste ps1.txt pwd.txt ps2.txt`

Can it be done without writing files? Or just generally less nightmarishly?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to make it a little less nightmarish:

```
#!/bin/bash
ps --no-headers -e -o pid,%cpu,%mem,args > ps_out.txt
awk '!/--no-headers/ { print $1 }' ps_out.txt | tee pids.txt | xargs pwdx 2>/dev/null > paths.txt
sed --in-place 's/://' paths.txt
awk 'FILENAME=="paths.txt" {pids[$1][0]=$2} FILENAME=="ps_out.txt" { pid=$1; $1=""; $0=$0; pids[pid][1]=$0} END {for( pid in pids ) {print pid, pids[pid][1], pids[pid][0]} }' paths.txt ps_out.txt
rm pids.txt paths.txt ps_out.txt
```

To make that `awk` script slightly more readable:

```
FILENAME=="paths.txt" {
   pids[$1][0]=$2
}
FILENAME=="ps_out.txt" {
   pid=$1;
   $1="";
   $0=$0;
   pids[pid][1]=$0
}
END {
   for( pid in pids ) {
      print pid, pids[pid][1], pids[pid][0]
   }
}
```